# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGPath" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native

I've already tried using React-native Link as well as Manual linking but the error is still persisting.
React-native-svg Version : 8.0.8

Answer (score 19):

I fixed the problem by explicitly installing the corresponding dependency.

```
yarn add react-native-svg
```

Comment: After installing the package, you need to `cd ios && pod install`

Comment: `npm install react-native-svg` for our npm boys and girls

Answer (score 13):

If on iOS, might try doing a `pod install` after you have done an `npm install`

1. Go to the iOS directory in your project.
2. Do a `pod install`
3. Open xcode and run again.

Answer (score 6):

running  `npx pod-install` should solve it.

Answer (score 5):

The below steps solved my issue.

```
npm install react-native-svg
npm install react-native-svg-transformer
```

Uninstall your exist app

```
react-native-run-android
```

I hope, It will help someone.

Answer (score 4):

you don't need to add any code, just use the command

```
npx react-native run-android
```

to run the project again

Answer (score 3):

See discussion and solutions here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/834

> react-native link is missing the last step. it is not adding "new
>   SvgPackage()"
>
> Open up `android/app/src/main/java/[...]/MainApplication.java Add new
>   SvgPackage() to the list returned by the getPackages() method. Add a
>   comma to the previous item if there's already something there.
>
> this is a bug and need to be fixed.

and

> In iOS this bug appeared in 7.0.2. To fix, in xcode go to Your_Project
>   / Build Phases / Link Binary With Libraries and add "libRNSVG.a"

Comment: libRNSVG.a not found

Comment: this is not working for me. react-native link adds "new SvgPackage()" statement anyways...

Comment: In the file open dialog, it appears as "RNSVG". Once you add it, it changes to "libRNSVG.a"

Answer (score 1):

Import package at MainApplication.java

`import com.horcrux.svg.SvgPackage;`

Then add package to list

`new SvgPackage()`

Answer (score 0):

Should run `npx pod-install` instead `pod install`. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall your Android app with `yarn` by issuing

`yarn run android`

which is

`npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Install this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg

```
npm i react-native-svg

npx react-native run-android
```